# swmenufree menu module not working Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

Whenever I try to install the swmenufree module for Joomla 1.6, it gives me an error xml setup file not found.

The setup file is present. Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have the version for 1.5 which will not work, the XML manifest is different and 1.6 cannot us it. The correct version is here - http://www.swmenupro.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=298&func=fileinfo&id=21